# moving a node and remove an attribute in the same row in xslt

Tags: xslt

Starting from the following document:

```
<foo>
  <bar>
    <items>
      <item attribull="true" name="foo" />
      <item attribull="false" name="bar" />
      <item attribull="true" name="foobar" />
    </items>
    (...)
  </bar>
</foo>
```

I'd like to produce the following document, where the `items` node is moved AND all `attribull` attributes are removed.

```
<foo>
  <items>
    <item name="foo" />
    <item name="bar" />
    <item name="foobar" />
  </items>
  <bar>
    (...)
  </bar>
</foo>
```

I know how to write a XSLT to move any node elsewhere and I know how to  write a XSLT to remove a specific attribute too BUT I don't know if it's possible to that with a **single** XSLT (in a single pass).

Any clue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply copy items (here via a default recursive rule), and then copy `<bar>` with all children *except* items. To delete all instances of an attribute, simply add an empty matching rule:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@attribull" />

<xsl:template match="bar">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="items"/>

  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|text()|*[not(self::items)]"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: `*[not(name()='items')]` is usually written as `*[not(self::items)]`.

Comment: @MartinHonnen Thanks, I canonicalized it. In the future, feel free to directly edit my posts if you spot possible improvements. Have a nice day!

Comment: Thanks! I'm wondering how different would have been the answer if I needed to move "items" into a totally different place, like a sub-sub-node of a sibling of "bar".